# How do I expose ingress on minikube to external hosts

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, minikube

I can set up Ingress on a minikube cluster as in this tutorial:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/

But then the service is reachable on the minikube ip only from the host which runs minikube.

How do I enable connections from other hosts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done with this command:

```
kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 deployment/ingress-nginx-controller 8443:443 --namespace ingress-nginx
```

Now the ingress can be reached from other hosts by

https://my.host.running.minikube:8443/

Comment: Isn’t port-forward considered as debugging mechanism? I might be wrong but perhaps it will not work for UDP.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the same page installing the minikube on a remote host.
Then to access to it from my localhost I have to run in the minikube the following command:

```
kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 web-746c8679d4-h47j4 8080:8080
```

The 0.0.0.0 means every address, it can be restricted.